# Jefferys' prior on variance (Var.) R

Tags: r, bayesian

Jefferys' prior on variance (Var.), although uninformative, is not flat, ***but it is equivalent to assuming that the logarithm of the variance is uniformly distributed on the real line***. So:

A) how I can see (plot) the **bold-faced** statement above in R?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in your question? Its not clear what you mean. You want to plot just the bold words or all words? Regarding the second question I don't think this forum is the place to ask math questions just programming.

Comment: Yes, the R code that can show how the bold-faced statement is correct? I edited my second question out.

Comment: ok I thought you were asking how to plot bold and regular text on the same graph, but it seems A is also a math question and not a programming one. I think you should post this on a math forum like http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://mathoverflow.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Make two plots. One with Jefferys' prior and the other with the log of Jefferys' prior. The latter should look uniform.

Comment: M_Fidino, thanks, could you be a bit more specific, you mean on the first plot, I put sigma^2 on the X axis and 1/Sigma^2 on the Y axis. BUT on the second plot, I put Log(sigma^2) on the X axis and 1/Sigma^2 on the Y axis?

Comment: What is the prior you are trying to use?

Comment: So, Jefferys' prior on variance (var) is: p(var) = 1/(var) this can be plotted as y = 1/x and of course is not flat. But, how can I show that the logarithm of the variance is uniformly distributed on the real line?